# GPG class for AJAX calls

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

I want to know if this GPG class in PHP is up to snuff as a professional-level class. I did my best to include everything and make it easy to use. I'm calling the object by invoke(). If anyone can figure anything I've missed, or how I can do better then, I'd really appreciate it.

This is a very simple codebase I made to interact with the GPG installation. I'm creating Filters for a JS package I created. The Filters are PHP and the direct codebase is JS.

```
<?PHP

class GPG {

    private $id;

    function __invoke(string $command, $param1 = "", $param2 = "", $param3 = "")
    {
        if (!isset($this->id))
            $this->id = gnupg_init();
        $tempFuncCall = 'gnupg_'.$command;

        $one_string = ["addencryptkey","decrypt","encrypt","encryptsign",
            "export","gettrustlist","import","keyinfo","listsignatures","setarmor","seterrormode","setsignmode","sign"];
        $two_strings = ["adddecryptkey","addsignkey","decryptverify"];
        $three_strings = ["verify"];
        if (in_array($command,$one_string))
        {
            return $tempFuncCall($this->id, $param1);
        }
        else if (in_array($command,$two_strings))
        {
            return $tempFuncCall($this->id, $param1, $param2);
        }
        else if (in_array($command,$three_strings))
        {
            return $tempFuncCall($this->id, $param1, $param2, $param3);
        }
        else if ($command != "init")
        {
            try
            {
                return $tempFuncCall($this->id);
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                echo "Command does not exist";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Here's an Example:

```
$gpg = new GPG();
$gpg('addencryptkey', "credentials");
$r = $gpg('encrypt',"this is just some text.");
$gpg('adddecryptkey',"credentials","");
echo $gpg('decrypt', $r);
// $r = $gpg('')
echo $r;
```

Comment: What is the supposed benefit over using php gnupg class here?

Comment: This is an API to create pre-cred-created cryptography straight from my JS package, PipesJS. It's at [PipesJS](https://www.github.com/wise-penny/pipes) for your worthy onlooking. It is a AJAX background filter, as I call them in the venue. Pipes is for UI designed related to UX production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that variable variables and variable function/method names should be avoided as much as possible (I nearly want to say: "NEVER use them").  These features often have a negative impact on the developer experience in IDEs.

I think you would benefit from reading PSR-12 coding guidelines.  Things that stand out to me are:

1. missing `__invoke()` method visibility declaration https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php
2. `if` without curly braces
3. type declarations on all `__invoke()` arguments
4. missing spaces after commas inside array declarations
5. placement of opening curly brace on `if` blocks
6. there should not be a space between `else if` -- it is one word in PHP

Beyond that, here are few other thoughts:

- `$one_string`, `$two_string`, and `$three_string` variable names are NOT awesome/intuitive/meaningful.  I see that these are whitelists and I don't really have an alternative to offer, but it doesn't strike me as "professional".  Should these even be variables at all? Would they be better as constants? Why are there three arguments after command anyhow?  Can the variable length parameters be simplified using the spread operator in the signature?

  What about:

  ```
  public function __invoke(string $command, string ...$params): mixed {
      //...
      return $tempFuncCall($this->id, ...$params);
      //...
  }
  ```
- I recommend strict comparisons unless logical to do otherwise. `$command !== "init"`

Comment: This is a good constructive set of contextual arguments for what you say, but it would make the code nothing but spaghetti. I truncated it the best I could. I will go and change the brackets though. I thank you for that. And I'll likely pass those other worldly.. umm you said spread signature? Does the called function divide them up?

Comment: Ookay, that deleted all the spaghetti. I never heard of how to use $params ... before. I apologize. It makes the whole thing just 29 lines with the example. Beautiful! Okay! Next!